# How do I receive post in which user being mentioned through Facebook API? (for IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to receive information what post with the content a user being mentioned on Facebook through Facebook API for iOS?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/user/feed